# Parsing telegram bot api response

Tags: python, aws-lambda, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to edit messages on telegram bot with the [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext), but it requires a *message_id* integer, so i need to somehow parse the telegram response when i send a message with

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot12345:abcdefghijk-lmnopqrstuvwxyz/sendMessage?text=Some%20Text&chat_id=123456789
```

it will respond with something like this :

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":213557,"from":{"id":bot_id,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"BotName","username":"SpaceTheBot"},"chat":{"id":123456789,"title":"A Group","type":"supergroup"},"date":1612928163,"text":"Some text"}}
```

so i wanna parse the message_id, so i can edit it later on.

Comment: Try this. Although this is for deleting messages, you can apply to edit messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761031/delete-outgoing-message-sent-by-telegram-bot-telegram-python/65919524#65919524

Comment: Hey! thank you for your response but i am **not** using a long polling method, i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to deserialize the response from Telegram. After that it will be a Python object. In this case because it is a JSON object it will be turned into a dict and can be accessed as such.

```py
import json

response = '{"ok":true,"result":{"message_id":213557,"from":{"id":"bot_id","is_bot":true,"first_name":"BotName","username":"SpaceTheBot"},"chat":{"id":123456789,"title":"A Group","type":"supergroup"},"date":1612928163,"text":"Some text"}}'
result = json.loads(response)

print(result["result"]["message_id"])
>>> 213557
```

If you are using requests, it has its own [JSON encorder/decoders](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)